# C++ Builder 2009 - Simple List of Ints

Tags: c++, list, c++builder, c++builder-2009

Coming from Java, I'm used to built in data structure that I can quickly/easily reference that allow me to do things like add integers to a list and check to see if an integer is in the list.

Since this seems to be common, I'm hoping to see what the easy way of doing this is C++ Builder is. I'm okay with using a standard C++ library too, as long as it will work with C++ Builder.

Comment: Have a look at all the standard containers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container Each one has pros and cons depending on the specific task. In your case it seems like you want a (multi)set or unordered_(multi)set. The standard library has to work with every c++ compiler.

Comment: I forgot, since you seem to be using an old compiler (2009), those containers marked `C++11` will not be available for you, including unordered_(multi)set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `std::vector` or `std::set`.  Use `vector` if you want to allow duplicates, use set if you don't.  Searching a `vector` will also be significantly slower in comparison to a `set`.

```
std::vector<int> intCheckList;
std::set<int> intCheckSet;
```

Comment: I got pulled onto a customer support issue, but I will look into this. As soon as I verify, then I'll accept if it works. Thx

Answer (score 1):

mattingly890's suggestion worked for me, this is just a follow up to give an example of how I used the set, as a reference for others. Below is some sample code on how I inserted into a set and tested to see if the value was in the set. Be sure to have `#include <set>` at the top.

```
// Test std set
std::set<int> myset;
std::set<int>::iterator it;
myset.insert(10);
myset.insert(20);
myset.insert(30);

it = myset.find(10);
boolean found = it!=myset.end();
if(found)
    MessageDlg("Found 10", mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);

it = myset.find(15);
found = it!=myset.end();
if(found)
    MessageDlg("Found 15", mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);

it = myset.find(20);
found = it!=myset.end();
if(found)
    MessageDlg("Found 20", mtInformation, TMsgDlgButtons() << mbOK, 0);
```

References:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/

Comment: `boolean` should be `bool` in c++, also there is `set::count()` which will return `0` or `1` instead of an iterator like `find` does. That would save you the test against `end()` and you could directly use it as the if-condition.